# Different outputs with/ without \newenvironment

Tags: environments, tabularx

I'm trying to setup my own CV without Curve. To do so, I intend to separate sections the same way with a `\newenvironment`.

```
%[...]
\newlength{\margin}
\setlength{\margin}{.3\textwidth}

\newcommand{\alinea}{\hspace{0.1cm}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{rubrique}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{M{\margin}|X}
} %
{\end{tabularx}}
```

But then in my document, the two blocks below give a different output :

```
% OKAY
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{\margin}|X}
Aout 2006 & Lorem Ipsum...
\end{tabularx}
```

--

```
% ERROR : File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body
\begin{rubrique}
Aout 2006 & Lorem Ipsum...
\end{rubrique}
```

I am certain to miss a point about `\newenvironment`, but which one ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The documentation of `tabularx` points out that you have to use `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` instead of `\begin{tabularx}` and `\end{tabularx}` when defining environments based on the `tabularx` environment.

Comment: It works fine, thank you (btw I use texStudio, which didn't recognize the function `\tabularx` at first :S)